# lasso regression prediction ignores index

Tags: python, arrays, scikit-learn, prediction, lasso-regression

I am building a ridge and lasso regression on the same dataset, however lasso model's prediction's shape seems different than ridge. I'd appreciate if someone can explain what I'm doing wrong...

```
###Ridge Regression
model3 = Ridge(alpha=5)
model3.fit(x_train2, y_train)

y_pred3=model3.predict(x_test2)
y_pred3.shape
#result is: (1542, 1)

###Lasso Regression
from sklearn.linear_model import Lasso

model4 = Lasso(alpha=0.1)
model4.fit(x_train2, y_train)

y_pred4=model4.predict(x_test2)
y_pred4.shape
#result is: (1542,)
```

Comment: Consider changing the title to something like "Lasso and Ridge models return different shapes for column vectors" or similar as I find your current one misleading.

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know why Lasso model's prediction is in a different shape but I solved my problem by reshaping the array as :

```
B = np.reshape(y_pred4, (-1, 1))
B
B.shape
##result: (1542,1)
```

Comment: Could also just guess, why Lasso returns a column vector and Ridge not. Don't know if that qualifies as a bug. Just want to add that it is slightly shorter to write B = y_pred4.reshape(-1, 1). Also if you want to achieve the opposite use ravel: C = y_pred3.ravel()